# Typed.js and Fontawesome

Tags: javascript, font-awesome, typed.js

Is it possible to have [typed.js](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/blob/master/README.md) work with fontawesome, so that it could for example, type a twitter icon?

Comment: another great question! upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever try this?

Fiddle: `https://jsfiddle.net/4L9a8z5w/`

Code:

```
$(".element").typed({
strings: ["<i class='fa fa-camera' /> is prohibited <i class='fa fa-ban'></i><i class='fa fa-camera' /> is prohibited <i class='fa fa-ban'></i><i class='fa fa-camera' /> is prohibited <i class='fa fa-ban'></i><i class='fa fa-camera' /> is prohibited <i class='fa fa-ban'></i><i class='fa fa-camera' /> is prohibited <i class='fa fa-ban'></i><i class='fa fa-camera' /> is prohibited <i class='fa fa-ban'></i><i class='fa fa-camera' /> is prohibited <i class='fa fa-ban'></i><i class='fa fa-camera' /> is prohibited <i class='fa fa-ban'></i>"],
typeSpeed: 0,
contentType: 'html'
})
```

You must set the contentType to 'html' so fontawesome can work.

Comment: For some damn reason, this its not working on my site. It just prints the html as text. But im fully aware your solution is ok. Anyone else having problems to implement?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write it like this. look at the "quotation marks":

```
strings: [`<i class="fa-solid fa-laptop-code"/> Developer`, "Designer"]
```

Not like this:

```
strings: ["<i class='fa-solid fa-laptop-code'/> Developer", "Designer"]
```